# Migrate SharePoint 2010 sites to SharePoint online (migrate the sites as-is)

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2010, migration, administration

We want to do a migration from SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint online using a tool named ShareGate. first thing we want to do, is to migrate the sites as-is. and we are planning to enable custom scripting on the modern online sites to mimic the SharePoint 2010. but will ShareGate be able to migrate those SP 2010 features to SharePoint online:-

1. Content Editor web part add inside pages
2. Customized list views using XSLT style
3. Workflow 2010
4. Customized master pages
5. Info path forms

so when we do the migration >> users can still work on the online sites as they use to work on the on-premises sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you cannot migrate

1. Info Path forms
2. Customized master pages
3. Workflow 2010
4. Customization using XSLT [Link](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1a42eca4-d76a-42e9-9532-bb2574494168/how-to-migrate-resourceresx-file-and-xslt-to-sharepoint-onlineoffice-365?forum=onlineservicessharepoint)

to SharePoint Online. You should be fine with content editor webparts, but I'm certain you can't stay on the SP2010 default UI and you'll have to migrate one way or another.

Since logins change, you'll need Azure AD, authentication needs to be setup and I wouldn't be optimistic to be able to do this giant leap and having people working just like in SP2010 in no time.

Comment: so there is not way to migrate any of these ? Info Path forms, Customized master pages, Workflow 2010, Customization using XSLT Link? Second question, to be able to migrate the Content Editor webparts, we should enable custom scripting first? and can we create the destination site as modern team/communication site >> enable custom scripts on it >> and do the migration to get the Content Editor web part?

Comment: I think you should ask this question to the guys at ShareGate, because it depends on what kind of code you're running inside your content editor webpart.

Comment: XSLT, workflow 2010, info path and custom master pages are technologies which are not supported in SharePoint online. There are other options to achieve the same kind of customization, but you can't get them by simply migrating to SharePoint online.

Comment: but we can enable Info path inside SP online (see thsi link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/configure-infopath-at-the-sharepoint-admin-center-on-office/) + Workflow 2010 can still exists inside SP online, but they will not run.. we need WF 2010 to get migrated so we can refer to them to redesign them using Power automate...

Comment: You wouldn't be able to create the 2010 workflows in the target environment to migrate them: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sharepoint-2010-workflow-retirement-1ca3fff8-9985-410a-85aa-8120f626965f

Comment: @CallumCrowley i do not want to create them .. i want them to get migrated into SharePoint 2010 to be able to open them using SP designer to redesign them.. is this possible ?

Comment: Migrating the workflow, by definition involves creating a workflow in the target to migrate the content of the workflow in to. Microsoft state that creating the 2010 workflow is no longer possible via SharePoint Designer.

Comment: @Callum Crowley ok what about `Customization using XSLT` & `Info Path forms`

Comment: MSFT is in the process of retiring InfoPath in Microsoft 365, I wouldn't recommend migrating them at all. With regards to XSLT, I wouldn't recommend migrating this and instead move to using modern SharePoint.